# Gradle sync failed when installing firebasae in my android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.aakash.rozgari"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle sync failed while installing firebase in my android studio.please help me solve this problem.I also get red underline in implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'

Comment: Please show both gradle files in full, both the project level build.gradle, and the app module build.gradle.

Comment: the project level build.gradle 
[link] https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iiXEXNWR00WftqaBdySdD4D9ZJyMt6GY

the app module build.gradle
[link] https://drive.google.com/open?id=179DLzurUu2QXUQqgqxszg3DDCz-N1E0u

Answer (score 0):

Update your project `build.gradle` to use the latest version of the plugin:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // <== CHANGED
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```